# How did Doctor Strange and company open so many portals in the end of Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, Doctor Strange brought allies through portals to fight Thanos and his army.

[image: Endgame Portals]

I can count 15 portals in this image. As all portals opened at the same time and Doctor Strange didn't have the Time Stone, this required at least 15 sling rings and 15 Sorcerers.

Given Sorcerers were limited in number (most either died or left), how did they open so many portals? Can multiple portals be opened at the same time?

Comment: Can you source any reference to 'most of them dieing or leaving?

Comment: I mean, 15 is a reasonable number when counting "limited", what's so unbelievable about that? Even if your presumption is correct, there would have been 100s if not 1000s of Wizards, so _only_ 15 seems to fit your theory anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because, simply put, not all of the Sorcerers died and we didn’t even get any indication that they did at all. Your assumption that they were limited is just plain false. Apart from the, relatively, small number of portals we see we also see a group of Sorcerers come through the portal led by Wong clearly showing there are quite a few of them left.

[image: Gif showing the heroes coming out of the portals including a group of Sorcerors led by Wong]

See at 1:30 in this video of the portal scene and even in your own image in the question:

And for what it’s worth this scene happens *after* Smart Hulk’s un-Snap so any Sorcerers who died to Thanos’ Snap would have come back already.

Comment: So you're saying he's Wong?

Comment: @Valorum I wouldn't put it in such Stark terms.

Comment: @Alarion - It would be Strange if you did.

Comment: You might want to put a Cap on those puns.

Comment: This has been a Banner comment section.

Comment: @Alarion - Yeah, it's not exactly been Loki.